# Winapi. GDI. Заполнить рабочую область частью bmp

Tags: winapi, bitmap, gdi

Есть bmp, с помощью которого (а точнее его частью) надо инициализировать рабочую область окна.

Самый простой для меня способ это использовать BitBlt в цикле, но понятно, что это очень нерационально. Поскольку с GDI я практически не знаком, то единственное решение, которое я придумал это создать кисть с помощью CreateDIBPatternBrushPt(), а затем закрасить окно  с помощью PatBlt(). И тут снова проблема, как создать DIB, являющийся частью моего bmp?

Собственно, вопрос. Корректен ли подобный подход и, если нет, то в каком направлении мне копать? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: "использовать BitBlt в цикле" что-то не соображаю, а зачем здесь цикл-то?

Comment: bmp размером 16x16, а мне этой картинкой надо все окно заполлнить

Comment: типа Tile нужно сделать? не пробовал, если честно. а что насчет GDIPlusовского Graphics::DrawImage? GDI+ очень нужная штука

Comment: да, наверное. Но у меня код на си и графику тоже хотелось бы в стиле  ближе к процедурному  оставить, поэтому надо gdi

Answer (score 1):

Создать битмап в памяти и заполнить его в цикле нужной картинкой при помощи bitblt. Затем одним движением инициализировать рабочую область окна. Если битмап больше не нужен (окно не будет менять размеры) - уничтожить битмап. Попробуй и посмотри на скорость. На рациональность пока забей - оптимизация будет дальше.